# Javascript send post data in asynchronous environment

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous

So my Problem is, that I get data from another server and im trying to send this received data to the same url to be able to retreive the data in PHP. I tried it with `fetch()`, `$.post()`, `$.ajax()`. Every time my xhr request is being cancelled by the browser for some unknown reason. Here is my current code:

```
function generateCodes()
    {
    var someVAR = document.getElementById("length").value;
    var someResult = createDataPromise("someVAR=" + someVAR);

    someResult.then((data) => 
        {
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax(
            {
            url: "sameURL",
            method: "post",
            data: jsonData,
            success: function(data)
                {
                console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });

    someResult.catch((error) =>
        {
        console.error("Server responded with error: " + error);
        });
    }

function createDataPromise(data)
    {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "externalServer");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.onload = () => resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        xhr.onerror = () => reject(xhr.statusText);
        xhr.send(data);
        });
    }
```

Is there any other possible solution to access the javascript object in PHP? (It is not possible to convert the varible because the javascript is in a pure js file)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the browser is blocking your request because of CORS. Modifying your request to be CORS compliant or making sure the remote response includes an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header would fix this.
Making sure your request is considered a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) would eliminate the possibility that it is being denied by a preflight request since you only need to send data and not receive it back in the javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it didn't fix my issue, still the same problem. Chrome still marks my xhr request as cancelled.

Comment: What exactly does Chrome say on the console and network tab of the developer tools?